# Only Root Routing works on Godaddy Server

Tags: php, apache, routes, godaddy-api

Trying to setup basic routing on godaddy, but only the first two cases work with the root but not for cases with words - browser returns Not Found. My guess is that instead of routing case it searched for a folder/file with the word in URL, nothing I tried worked.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)＄ index.php
```

index.php:

```
<?php

$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$viewDir = '/';

switch ($request) {
    case '':
    case '/':
        require __DIR__ . $viewDir . 'home.html';
        break;

    case '/test':
        require __DIR__ . $viewDir . 'boost.html';
        break;
}
```

Hosting type: Deluxe Linux Hosting with cPanel

Even with deleted .htaccess code the first two cases in index.php work. I renamed index.php file and even root routing doesn't work - which means htaccess never worked. Godaddy on shared hosting doesn't allot apache config access but allows to configure .htaccess file.

Comment: Are they running Apache (which is the webserver that uses htaccess)? If so, is the Apache module mod_rewrite installed and enabled? If so, is Apache configured to read/use htaccess files? I don't know cPanel so I can't guide you on how to check those things.

Comment: I don't know what hosting provides. Based on their article you can just change the htaccess file. But I just renamed php file and even root routing doesn't work - which means htaccess never worked. I will have to search godaddy for what you mentioned.

Comment: I found that Godaddy on shared hosting doesn't allow apache config access but allows to configure .htaccess file.

Comment: _"I don't know what hosting provides"_ - You should know that. If you don't, contact them and find out. Why do you have a hosting solution without knowing if it even supports your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the mod_rewrite old recipes we still suffer and see, all questions like this should just go to a more modern/actual and simple approach which does not need mod_rewrite at all.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php # if necessary/needed
FallbackResource /index.php
```

The first one will look for index.php when a directory path is requested, as in with a trailing slash.

The second one will load /index.php when a request points to a non-static or non-existent element.

Modules needed for this: **mod_dir**

Comment: Looks like it might work thanks for the comment! But I'm going to stick to the current solution since. It might be modern but modern means new, not a reason why it's good.
Sorry I can't look at mod_dir without seeing the face.

Comment: @listak I didn't mean modern as in new, but as current. mod_rewrite recipes for simple solutions should be forgotten, you don't smash a fly with a cannon and such. Anyways, use what suits you best, but convolution leads to mess and mess to problems later on, same happens with greedy expressions like .*

Answer (score 0):

Changing the rule a bit worked: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

Thanks everybody for the helpful comments!